# Not work indexOf() for array that is from ajax text file data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, split, indexof

jQuery version 1.4.4

aaa.txt
includes just 3row
01000
01001
01139

```
$.ajax({

        url: "aaa.txt", 
        success: function(result){
            console.log(result);
            var rArr = result.split("\n");
            var ee = rArr.indexOf("01001");
            console.log(ee);
        }
});

return -1.
```

I guess it should return 1. All the type are the string.

I can't understand why this situation happens.

Answer (score 1):

```
   var rArr = result.split(" ");// in this line you are spliting
   var ee = rArr.indexOf("01001");// so if it is array you can not use indexOf it will work on sring.
```

---

```
  var ee = rArr[index].indexOf("01001");//index should be according to your need
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check your file and see it is actually using which linefeed. For example, if your file is from written by Windows Notepad, then it uses `\r\n` and so your `.split()` yields `["01000\r","01001\r","01139"]` and so `.indexOf()` returns -1, as `"01001"!=="01001\r"`.

Answer (score 0):

I had to look at the source code of your question to determine this, but you end each line of the input data with a space.

```
"01001 " !== "01001"
```

You need to either:

- Remove the space from the input file
- Match it in the test
- Remove it (with [trim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim)) from each member of the array (with [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)).